Wget show error certificate of <domain> name was signed using an insecure algorithm, while curl works
We are trying to check domain
wget domain <like httpx://abc.com>
we are getting error  "The certificate of domain(abc.com) was signed using an insecure algorithm. But SSL certificate is issued by Let's encrypt 2
048 bit RSA
Public Key: RSA 2048 bits
Signature algorithm:
PKCS #1 SHA-256 With RSA Encryption
We are using RHEL 9.3 . Curl works without any certificate error.
Can anybody help to fix issue?

Use --no-check-certificate to bypass this warning until you can fix your certificate.

Is your wget binary linked against OpenSSL (libssl) or against GnuTLS or against MozNSS? Is your libcurl linked against OpenSSL or GnuTLS or NSS?

Most likely gnuTLS. Tell us how to check on RHEL 9.3?
